# How to display number to **** ****

Tags: javascript, react-native

I want convert number to * and add space after every 4 digits.
ex: 12345678 -> 1234 5678 -> **** ****
Now i just convert number to * but can't add space . ( when convert number to * , add space function not work )
Please help me!

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, TextInput, View } from 'react-native';

export default class PizzaTranslator extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {text: ''};
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{padding: 10}}>
        <TextInput
          style={{height: 40}}
          placeholder="Type here to translate!"
          onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({text})}
          value={this.state.text}
        />
        <Text style={{padding: 10, fontSize: 42}}>
{this.state.text.replace(/(\(-?\d+(?:\.\d*){4})/g,'$1').replace(/(^\s+|\s+$)/,'') .slice(20).padStart(this.state.text.length, '*')}
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

i expect 
input : 123456789123 
output: **** **** ****

Comment: You said you succeeded to convert the number to `*` but can't add space. So your issue is exactly like the one above.

Comment: yes i can convert number to * . Like 12345678 -> ******** . but when it's **** , i can't add space . Add space just work with a->Z or 0 -> 9 . not work with *

Comment: Then add the function _before_ converting to `**** ****`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One line Answer:

```
"123456781234".replace(/[0-9]/g, "*").match(/.{1,4}/g).join(" ");
```

Comment: i work with textInput so when start  TextInput = ''
https://snack.expo.io/SJTEASkcB?session_id=snack-session-nMkyeVZjL

Answer (score 1):

Try this for grouping

```
this.state.text.replace(/[^\dA-Z]/g, '').replace(/(.{4})/g, '$1 ').trim();
```

Edit: how to split '********' in javascript

```
var str = "************";
var chuncks = str.match(/.{1,4}/g);
var new_value = chuncks.join(" "); //returns **** **** ****
```

Following will be the complete answer after combining the above two:

```
var starString = "123456781234".replace(/[0-9]/g, "*");
var chuncks = starString.match(/.{1,4}/g);
var new_value = chuncks.join(" "); //returns **** **** ****
```

Comment: it's the same replace(/(\(-?\d+(?:\.\d*){4})/g,'$1').replace(/(^\s+|\s+$)/,'')  but both not work when convert to ****

Comment: see my edit on how to split

Comment: it's TextInput so when str = '' -> chuncks will be null .
```
export function convertString(text) {
    var str = (text).slice(20).padStart(text.length, '*')
    var chuncks = str.match(/.{1,4}/g);
    if (chuncks === null || chuncks === undefined || chuncks === '') {
        chuncks = ["*"]
    } else {
        var new_value = chuncks.join(" ");
    }
    return new_value
}
```
i follow your code and solved by this way . Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could just go oldskool and use a loop. :-)

```
const num = 123456789123456789;
const preStr = num.toString();
let postStr = "";

for(var i = 0; i < preStr.length; i++){
    postStr += '*';
    i % 4 === 3 && (postStr += ' ');
}
console.log(postStr)
// output: **** **** **** **** **
```

As a function:

```
const format = input => {
    let output = "";
    for(var i = 0; i < preStr.length; i++){
        output += '*';
        i % 4 === 3 && (output += ' ');
    }
    return output;
}
console.log(format("123456789123456789"));

// output: **** **** **** **** **
```